# Why is my onchange function called twice when using .focus()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, focus, onchange

**TLDR**

- Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/k4WKH/1/) in chrome.
- Type someting and press `tab`. see one new box appear
- type something and press `enter`. see two new boxes appear, where one is expected.

**Intro**
I noticed that when using `enter` rather then `tab` to change fields, my onchange function on an input field was firing twice. This page was rather large, and still in development (read: numerous other bugs), so I've made a minimal example that shows this behaviour, and in this case it even does it on 'tab'. This is only a problem in **Chrome** as far as I can tell.

**What it should do**
I want to make a new input after something is entered into the input-field. This field should get focus.

**Example:**

javascript - needing jquery

```
function myOnChange(context,curNum){
      alert('onchange start');
      nextNum = curNum+1;
      $(context.parentNode).append('<input type="text" onchange="return myOnChange(this,'+nextNum+')" id="prefix_'+nextNum+'" >');
      $('#prefix_'+nextNum).focus();
      return false;
}
```

HTML-part

```
<div>
    <input type="text" onchange="return myOnChange(this,1);" id="prefix_1">
</div>
```

*the complete code is [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cDEk4fWi). you need to add your path to jquery in the script*

A working example is here on [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4WKH/1/)

The onchange gets called twice: The `myOnChange` function is called, makes the new input, calls the `focus()`, the `myOnChange` gets called again, makes a new input, the 'inner' `myOnChange` exits and then the 'outer' `myOnchange` exits.

I'm assuming this is because the focus change fires the `onchange()`?. I know there is some difference in behaviour between browsers in this.

I would like to stop the .focus() (which seems to be the problem) to NOT call the `onchange()`, so `myOnChange()` doesn't get called twice. Anybody know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix (untested) should be to defer the call to `focus()` via

```
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0);
```

until after the event handler has terminated.

However, it is possible to make it work without such a hack; jQuery-free example code:

```
<head>
<style>
input { display: block; }
</style>
<body>
<div></div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

var field = document.createElement('input');
field.type = 'text';
field.onchange = function() {
    // only add a new field on change of last field
    if(this.num === div.getElementsByTagName('input').length)
        div.appendChild(createField(this.num + 1));

    this.nextSibling.focus();
};

function createField(num) {
    var clone = field.cloneNode(false);
    clone.num = num;
    clone.onchange = field.onchange;
    return clone;
}

div.appendChild(createField(1));
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like a good method, but since i might need to use the "remove onchange" hack anyway, i'll go with that I think. Quick test does seem to indicate that this works though, +1 :)

Comment: Note: I have not used this method, but it looks like the best answer to the question. My problem had some more issues, and so I've used the answer I provided below, but still marked this one as accepted ;)

Answer (score 7):

There's a way easier and more reasonable solution. As you expect onchange fire when the input value **changes**, you can simply explicitly check, if it was actually changed.

```
function onChangeHandler(e){
  if(this.value==this.oldvalue)return; //not changed really
  this.oldvalue=this.value;
  // .... your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm `myOnChange` gets called twice on Chrome. But the `context` argument is the initial input field on both calls.

<strike>If you remove the alert call it only fires once. If you are using the alert for testing only then try using console instead (although you need to remove it for testing in IE).</strike>

**EDIT:** It seems that the change event fires twice on the enter key. The following adds a condition to check for the existence of the new field.

```
function myOnChange(context, curNum) {
      nextNum = curNum+1;

      if ($('#prefix_'+nextNum).length) return false;// added to avoid duplication

      $(context.parentNode).append('<input type="text" onchange="return myOnChange(this,'+nextNum+')" id="prefix_'+nextNum+'" >');
      $('#prefix_'+nextNum)[0].focus();
      return false;
}
```

**Update:**

The `$('#prefix_'+nextNum).focus();` does not get called because focus is a method of the dom object, not jQuery. Fixed it with `$('#prefix_'+nextNum)[0].focus();`.

Comment: The alert is indeed for testing only :). I have removed it, but that still makes a double call unfortunately.

Comment: ahh yes. I was tabbing. I get the double on enter.

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle example

Comment: +1 for help on the focus problem. I will use the sollution I came up with, but this is helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
var curNum = 1;
function myOnChange( context )
{
    curNum++;

    $('<input type="text" onchange="return myOnChange( this )" id="prefix_'+ curNum +'" >').insertAfter( context );
    $('#prefix_'+ curNum ).focus();

    return false;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4axh/).

Comment: That still creates two textboxes on `enter`

Comment: I'm sorry, that does indeed make 2 new fields on enter :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that because of the `focus()`, the onchange is called again. I don't know if this is a good sollution, but this adding this to the function is a quick sollution:

```
context.onchange = "";
```

(The onchange is called again, but is now empty. This is also good because this function should never be called twice. There will be some interface changes in the final product that help with problems that would arise from this (mistakes and all), but in the end this is something I probably would have done anyway).

sollution here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4WKH/2/

As @johnhunter says, the focus does not work in the example, but it does in my complete code. I haven't looked into what's going on there, but that seems to be a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this some help to anybody, for any reason, in chrome when you attach an event onchage to a input text, when you press the enterkey, the function in the event, do it twice, i solve this problem chaged the event for onkeypress and evaluate the codes, if i have an enter then do the function, cause i only wait for an enterkey user's, that not works for tab key.

```
    input_txt.onkeypress=function(evt){ 
            evt = evt || window.event;
            var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
            if(charCode === 13)  evaluate( n_rows ); 
             };
```