# Javascript For Loop keeps doubling up my divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a script that creates a number of fields based on a number the user inputs (k).

I originally wrote a script that would create the correct number of fields. However I wanted to arrange them like vectors on the screen, so I adapted my script.

I wanted the following script to create the correct number of fields and place them in DIVS, so I could lay them out as I wish on the page.

Since doing this, the script now produces duplicate DIVS as iff it runs through the loop twice, but I can't for life of me work out why...

```
function createFields(k)
{
k=k+1

for (var n=1; n<k; n++) {

    var makeBox=document.createElement("div");
    makeBox.id = "box" + n;
    document.getElementById("top").appendChild(makeBox);
    document.getElementById("box" + n).setAttribute('class',"box");

    var addOpen=document.createElement("div");
    addOpen.id = "open"+n;
    document.getElementById("box" + n ).appendChild(addOpen);
    document.getElementById("open" + n).setAttribute('class',"open");

    var vectorBox=document.createElement("div");
    vectorBox.id = "vector" + n;
    document.getElementById("box" + n).appendChild(vectorBox);
    document.getElementById("vector" + n).setAttribute('class',"vect");

    var xVector=document.createElement("div");
    xVector.id = "top" + n;
    document.getElementById("vector" + n).appendChild(xVector);
    document.getElementById("top" + n).setAttribute('class',"xVect");

    var newx=document.createElement("input");
    newx.id = "x" + n;
    document.getElementById("top" + n).appendChild(newx);
    document.getElementById("x" + n).setAttribute('name',"x" + n);
    document.getElementById("x" + n).setAttribute('type',"text");
    document.getElementById("x" + n).setAttribute('size',"4");
    document.getElementById("x" + n).setAttribute('maxlength',"4");

    var yVector=document.createElement("div");
    yVector.id = "bottom" + n;
    yVector.class = "yVect";
    document.getElementById("vector" + n).appendChild(yVector);
    document.getElementById("bottom" + n).setAttribute('class',"yVect");

    var newy=document.createElement("input");
    newy.id = "y" + n;
    document.getElementById("bottom" + n).appendChild(newy);
    document.getElementById("y" + n).setAttribute('name',"y" + n);
    document.getElementById("y" + n).setAttribute('type',"text");
    document.getElementById("y" + n).setAttribute('size',"4");
    document.getElementById("y" + n).setAttribute('maxlength',"4");

    var addClose=document.createElement("div");
    addClose.id = "close"+n;
    document.getElementById("box" + n ).appendChild(addClose);
    document.getElementById("close" + n).setAttribute('class',"close");

    }
}
```

Any clues?

**UPDATED:**

The Code is called via another function:

```
function getVectors()
{
v = document.getElementById("vectorN").value;
v=parseInt(v); //turn the text into an integer
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML="Enter your Vectors below!";
createFields(v);
document.getElementById("enter").innerHTML="<input type=\"button\" id=\"button\" value=\"Submit Numbers\" onclick=\"canvas()\"/>";

}
```

Which is called by onchange in the html:

```
<p id="q1">How many Vectors will you need?
        <input id="vectorN" name="vectorN" type="text" onChange="getVectors()" size="4" maxlength="4">
      </p>
```

**Further UPDATE**

After checking the console.log,
the only place that calls createFields() is the getVectors() function. It does appear to be calling createFields twice (despite only doing so once in the script).
The ONLY place that calls getVectors() is the onChange event in the input field.
Is it possible that when I change the innerHTML and remove the input field that this is being registered as an onChange event and calling the function again?

Comment: @Ismail Pure javascript is faster

Comment: @Ismail: The verbosity displayed in the code can be easily eliminated without resorting to a large DOM library.

Comment: I have no idea.
I'm taking the input from the fields to draw on a HTML 5 canvas.
To draw on the canvas I need a javascript (from looking on W3C schools today.)
Do you know why it's apears to be going through the loop twice?

Comment: How is `createFields()` invoked?

Comment: @Maffster Check my answer. I guess you're calling the function twice.

Comment: Regarding your update, that could be. I'd really avoid doing `.innerHTML` manipulation to update the DOM. If you want to toggle between two buttons, then put them both in the original document, and update their CSS `display`. Have you checked if `getVectors()` is also invoked twice?

Comment: getVectors() was being called twice - so I'm putting it down to the .innerHTML  
For a temp fix I've used an if statement with a variable to check if the function has been called before.
Finished page is here: [link](http://snhs.im/ict/vectors/vectors.html)

Comment: Seems to work as exepcted in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8Ly/1/

Comment: @JonP - I followed your link - and it doubled up for me...

Comment: I'm not sure what is being doubled up. You have an `x` & `y` pair of inputs for each vector. I.e if you enter 3 you should have 6 inputs. This is what I get in Firefox anyway. The console log indicates each function is only being called once.

Comment: except I get 12...  
I've just taken a screenshot of what I get when I enter "2"  [link](https://flic.kr/p/nETSx9)  
I should get 4 fields but I get 8.

Comment: Can you replicate this in different browsers? What OS and browser did you use for the screen shot? Do you get the same with a button press: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8Ly/3/ or onBlur: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8Ly/4/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166086/why-is-my-onchange-function-called-twice-when-using-focus) sheds some light on the problem. I'd been tabbing out of the text box, which only triggers the `onChange` event once. Pressing enter fires it twice, which is the problem you were getting.

There are a  couple of ways to get around this. I've chosen to keep track of the number of fields entered. If this changes, generate the fields. If not do nothing.

```
var fields = 0;

function createFields(k) {
    if (k != fields) {
        fields = k;
        console.log("Fields: " + k);

        //Rest of the code the same;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8Ly/5/

You could also do something similar in the `getVectors()` function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At least I know WHY it's happening now. 
I had put a similar trap on my getVectors() function to get it working as I wanted. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks fine. aren't you just calling the function twice? Do a console.log right after `function createFields(k) {` to check if that's the case. Maybe 2 event listeners on the field where the user inputs k (onkeyup, change)?

If you're not sure where you call createFields from. Do a find in all files and look for createFields. Add a `console.log('Calling createFields from here');` just before you call createFields.

Comment: Just add to your function createFields a line. The first line. And that lines says: `console.log('createFields called with these arguments:', arguments);`

Comment: @Maffster Add how you call createFields to your original question. That code here in the comments is hard to read.

Comment: Update your original question again. We should not chat 1-on-1 in the comments. That's not where comments are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "creating" all the elements with the DOM why not build a "string" and then set a container objects `.innerHTML = the_string` value? This way it won't matter if the function gets called twice because it will simply overwrite itself the second time and produce the same output.